# Is it possible to trigger events using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have just started using [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org/) and find myself continuously turning to jQuery to help in certain situations. Most recently I have attempted to, unsuccessfully "trigger" (or emulate) an event, such as an on click or blur event.

I know in jQuery you can do the following:

```
$('#my-selector').trigger('click');
```

But how can this be acheived using Vue.js? I am wanting to move away from using jQuery as much as possible.

Take the below as an example:

```
<div id="my-scope">
    <button type="button" v-on="click: myClickEvent">Click Me!</button>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: "#my-scope",
    data: {
        foo: "Hello World"
    },
    methods: {
        myClickEvent: function(e) {
            console.log(e.targetVM);
            alert(this.foo);
        },
        anotherRandomFunciton: function() {
            this.myClickEvent();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

If I was to call **anotherRandomFunciton**, I would like it to emulate (or trigger) the above click event. However, I attempt this the event (or **e** in the above example) never gets passed to the function.

Does Vue.js have a method for achieving this?

Comment: Are you okay with using plain javascript?

Comment: I guess so, but if that's the case I may as well just use jQuery. I just though there may have been a better way to do this using Vue.js

Comment: Did you check out the instance methods? You're able to call events there and listen to events in a more jQuery fashion. http://vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html

Comment: You're trying to simulate a click event though so that link probably won't help either.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You need to get a reference to your button by using `v-el` like so:

```
<button type="button" @click="myClickEvent" v-el:my-btn>Click Me!</button>
```

Then, in your method:

```
function anotherRandomFunction() {
    var elem = this.$els.myBtn
    elem.click()
}
```

It's just a native DOM click event. See [`v-el` Documentation](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-el)

Or since Vue 2.x:

```
<template>
    <button type="button" @click="myClickEvent" ref="myBtn">
        Click Me!
    </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        myClickEvent($event) {
            const elem = this.$refs.myBtn
            elem.click()
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Since Vue uses and listens for native DOM events only. You can trigger native DOM events using the [`Element#dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) like so:

```
var elem = this.$els.myBtn; // Element to fire on

var prevented = elem.dispatchEvent(new Event("change")); // Fire event

if (prevented) {} // A handler used event.preventDefault();
```

This is not exactly ideal or best practice. Ideally, you should have a function that handles the internals and an event handler that calls that function. That way, you can call the internals whenever you need to.

Comment: It has been replaced in Vue2: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-el-and-v-ref-replaced. You should now use [#ref](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)

Answer (score 42):

If someone stumbles upon this, this is how I did it:

When using **`this.$refs.myBtn.click()`**

I get

> *“Uncaught TypeError: this.$refs.myBtn.click is not a function”*

Changed it to: **`this.$refs.myBtn.$el.click()`**

To be clear: “**`$el`**” needs to be added for it to work.

Comment: I think this might depend on your code and/or version of Vue. `this.$refs.filterGroupLegend.click()` works for me with 2.5.16.

Comment: @the_dude_abides It depends if you're handling the click on a component or a native DOM element. Use `$el` for native elements. Side note, sweet handle maan

Comment: Thanks @james.brndwgn !

Comment: i was trying to trigger `@remove` event for a component, `this.$refs.pictureInput.remove()` shows error saying it is not a function as you said, so when using `this.$refs.pictureInput.$el.remove()` it calls the native `remove()` i guess and removes the element from the view. any suggestions to avoid this?

Comment: okay, so i was trying to invoke a method call actually, and the name of the method was wrong, my bad! after getting the name right, it worked.

Comment: For me works without `$el` part but maybe something changed.

Answer (score -8):

Vue is by its nature narrowly focused – it is intended that other packages like jQuery (EDIT: for jQuery features *other* than DOM manipulation) to be used with it. I think using jQuery's `trigger` is just fine.

However, if you want to create your own events without jQuery, check out `dispatchEvent`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

Or, for the particular case of click, there is a method on DOM elements you can use:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: I don't think this statement is true...
>it is intended that other packages like jQuery be used with it

Comment: @Grant from the perspective that you only want Vue modifying the DOM, you are correct. But generally speaking, Vue has a pretty narrow focus and it is easy to incorporate other packages such as Sortable.js so you end up with something like Vue.Draggable.

Comment: This answer is absolutely wrong. Vue is meant to replace jquery. Using jquery with vue is a hack at best, and is absolutely bad practice.

Comment: Vue is not meant to replace jQuery. Vue is meant to replace direct DOM manipulation. jQuery can be used for more than DOM manipulation.

Comment: Absolutely not - Using jQuery with any modern SPA JS Framework is a pretty fair indication that you're not using the framework properly.