# Listeners on elements of a VueJS application outside the Vuejs instance not working in Firefox and IE but working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, dom, vuejs2

Summary of my application scenario: I have created a Vuejs application which can work with different web applications. Vuejs application script included in any web page will replace a div element on integrating web page and on certain actions of user on the page, the Vuejs application renders response to hidden input fields and web application should listen to any change events on those hidden fields to determine any changes to response

Problem:

Native DOM events triggered inside Vuejs application are not captured by listeners outside Vuejs Instance

I have native DOM change events on input field triggered in Vuejs application and also triggered them on elements using { this.$refs } to refer the actual DOM element and then added listeners on the integrating web page for any change events but Listeners are not firing in IE and firefox though everything is working as expected in chrome.

Can someone suggest me any solution for addressing this issue ?

I am aware of listening using " vm.$on " outside Vue instance but I want to keep the client integration seam less to framework and use the native dom listeners to identify any change to input fields.

Here is code sample code to explain

Related issues found but didn't work for this case:

[Is it possible to trigger events using Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917889/is-it-possible-to-trigger-events-using-vue-js#)

App component:- Added a hidden text field and a button that changes the value of the text field using javascript which in turn will trigger change event on the hidden field.

Web page: So when I am trying to listen to change events on a web page, listeners do not fire though change events are triggered inside Vuejs application via native events using javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head title = "TestPage">
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', 
      function (event) {
         var element = document.getElementById("test-field");
         element.addEventListener('change', function () {
         console.log("Change event captured")
      })
  })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id = "divelementidtoreplace" type = "text" >
</body>
</html>

<template>
  <div id="app">
      <input type="hidden" id = "test" v-model = 'value' ref="inputFieldToListen">
       <button @click= "changeHiddenInputFieldvalue()" > click to change the text  </button >
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: {
    value: ''
  }
  methods: {
    changeHiddenInputFieldvalue: function () {
        this.value = 'This assigned can put random value to test the trigger';
    },
    triggerChangeEvent: function (element) {
      if (element) {
        if ('createEvent' in document) {
          var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents')
          evt.initEvent('input', true, true)
          element.dispatchEvent(evt)
        }
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value: function (NewValue, oldValue) {
      this.triggerChangeEvent(this.$refs.inputFieldToListen)
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

main.js: -

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

var vueInstance = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {

  },
  template: '<App />',
})
```

Comment: You can't mount your app in `input` field, use `el:"#app"`

Comment: As you said I am mounting my app to a <div> element with id = 'app', above code being sample code I have mentioned it as "#divelementidtoreplace" i.e #app

Comment: try to use `@click` instead of `onclick`

Comment: Used @click and actual question is why are native DOM events fired on VueJS elements not caught by listeners outside Vuejs ? from debugging I am sure that code that triggers DOM change event is executed in Vuejs, but not sure why they are not caught in IE and firefox ? while the same code works in google chrome --> events are fired and also caught by listeners

Comment: Can you please - in this question and all future questions you might ask on StackOverflow - **take care that your code is properly indented and thus, readable**?

Comment: sure, I corrected the code format for this post now.