# How can I programmatically trigger ripple effect on a Vuetify.js component?

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I have a v-btn with ripple enabled. Is there a way to programmatically trigger the ripple effect? Is this possible if I use v-ripple directive on another component of my own that wraps the button?

I need to draw the users attention to the button in an unobtrusive way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917889/is-it-possible-to-trigger-events-using-vue-js

Comment: I found that question before. I can get the button to click by calling click() or dispatching a click event to it, but that doesn't trigger the ripple effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to dispatch a "mousedown" event with clientX and clientY filled in to trigger the ripple and then a "mouseup" to get rid of it.

I have a utility method in CompUtil.js:

```
export default {

  ripple: function($el) {
    let ev = new Event("mousedown")
    let offset = $el.getBoundingClientRect()
    ev.clientX = offset.left + offset.width/2
    ev.clientY = offset.top + offset.height/2
    $el.dispatchEvent(ev)

    setTimeout(function() {
      $el.dispatchEvent(new Event("mouseup"))
    }, 300)
  }
}
```

Then I can do:

```
<v-btn ref="help" ...>

CompUtil.ripple(this.$refs.help.$el)
```

Comment: Quick question, does this not trigger the click event on the button hence calling the click event handler?

Comment: Not it doesn't appear to

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like that

```
<v-btn :ripple=“your_expression”></v-btn>
```

You can check vuetify documentation.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/ripples

Comment: As far as I can tell that property just controls if the button does the ripple thing when clicked. I tried toggling that on and off and it doesn't do ripple.

Comment: Yes, I understand your question wrongly. Maybe you can trigger a click event programmatically?