# Why is $el sometimes necessary when using $refs in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I was using a piece of code like the following to trigger a *click* event when the *ENTER* key is pressed:

```
<q-tab-panel name="option1" @keyup.enter.native="$refs.button.click()">
...
  <q-btn ref="button" @click="function()" />
...
</q-tab-panel>
```

The tags belong to components of the *Quasar Framework*. This piece of code was working not so long ago but now it takes this change to work:

```
<q-tab-panel name="option1" @keyup.enter.native="$refs.button.$el.click()">
```

That is, now using the reference `$refs.button.click()` generates an error when *ENTER* is pressed:

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultPrevented' of undefined"

Why was it working before and why is it not working now? I have seen someone mention that it has to do with the version of Vue or the fact that the reference is being used in a component and not a native DOM element. See [Is it possible to trigger events using Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917889/is-it-possible-to-trigger-events-using-vue-js]). I have also seen [Vue - when and why using $el](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392699/vue-when-and-why-using-el), which does not answer why before it worked and now it does not.

The Vue documentation says the following about `$el`:

> The root DOM element that the Vue instance is managing.

Which makes sense but does not explain either why before it was not needed. In my case, the error happens with Vue 2.6.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, a `$ref` returns an instance of a Vue component. `click()` is a method meant to be called on a DOM element (although you could add a `click` method to your component). To call it you need actual DOM elements, which is what `$el` is for. `$el` returns the DOM node to which a given Vue instance is attached.

That being said, my best guess for why it worked before and why it doesn't work anymore, is that Vue changed this behavior from one version to the other, and you noticed it when (if) you changed versions.

Another possible reason for the difference is that maybe on your previous use cases you were using refs on tags which were not Vue components, but common HTML tags. In that case, a `$ref` would still return a DOM node.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I think that it is either Vue or Quasar that has changed something, because I have not changed the code that was working before. It may be as simple as not having now a `click()` method in the `<q-tab-panel>` component. I will wait for other answers but yours sounds pretty good!